# Orient Rotation to Movement Option dosen’t work

Tags: unreal-engine5, behavior-tree

video link : https://forums.unrealengine.com/t/orient-rotation-to-movement-option-dosent-work/772531

[image]

this is Behavior Tree when Zombie detects player, than chase player by Move To node.
but as you know, Move To node makes character’s rotation stuttering.
So I tried uncheck Use Controller Yaw, check Orient Rotaions to Movement Option, and Set Rotation Rate to (0, 0, 720) like this:

[image]

but setting this options makes AI just goes forward, like the video shows.
why this happening? I can’t find why.

Answer (score 0):

Set AnimBP's Root Motion Mode to 'Ignore Root Motion', than it works.